# ReactJS JSX Syntax for If-Else

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following jsx code, I am trying to put some code out of the mapping function, but getting errors with the jsx syntax, I want this block displayed only if there is some data..

```
{this.props.someData ? 
  <div className="container">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div className="block1">
      <button>one</button>
      <buttontwo</button>
    </div>  
    this.props.someData.map((response, index) => {
      return ( 
        <div className="Block2">  
          <div key={index}>
            <span>{response.number}</span>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div> 
    );
}) : ''}
```

Comment: If one of the answers is correct, click the empty check mark next to the answer to mark it correct. Otherwise, refine the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
{this.props.someData ? 
     <div className="container">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <div className="block1">
              <button>one</button>
              <buttontwo</button>
          </div>  
          {this.props.someData.map((response, index) => {
              return ( 
                 <div className="Block2">  
                    <div key={index}>
                     <span>{response.number}</span>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              )})
           }
     </div> 
: <div/>}
```

**Mistake you are doing:**

To render any js code inside html elements, `{}` is required, since you are rendering `JSX` if the condition is true and inside that using `map` so put `map` function inside `{}`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a child `{` wrapping your map. You have a few other errors as well. You were cosing your tags and braces too early. Additionally, an "empty" JSX element should return null, not empty string. You also have broken syntax with no closing `>` here: `<buttontwo</button>`

Using a code editor that provides syntax highlighting, and using consistent spacing, and always using eslint to check for errors, will help prevent the need to come to StackOverflow and blocking your programming on syntax questions.

```
{this.props.someData ?
    <div className="container">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <div className="block1">
            <button>one</button>
            <button>two</button>
        </div>
        { this.props.someData.map((response, index) => {
            return (
                <div className="Block2">
                    <div key={index}>
                        <span>{response.number}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }) }
    </div> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your meaning correctly, I think this would do:

```
 {this.props.someData &&  
  (<div className="container">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div className="block1">
      <button>one</button>
      <buttontwo</button>
    </div>  
    {this.props.someData.map((response, index) => {
      return ( 
        <div className="Block2">  
          <div key={index}>
            <span>{response.number}</span>
          </div>
        </div> 
      );
    })}
  </div>) 
}
```

I'd recommend you to have a look at the conditional rendering section of the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical-ampamp-operator).