# React if/else within JSX

Tags: json, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

I am fetching JSON data from an API and then need to display it in a react component. I need to use if/else conditions. For ex. The duration returned by the JSON data might turn out to be 0 or it might not be set at all, in that case, I need to avoid displaying it on the screen. So I need an if/else conditioning inside the row class and display Duration data only if it is being provided by the API, how can I achieve that? I read that JSX doesn't support if/else, what's the alternative in that case?

```
      <div className="row">
        //if condition needs to go here
        <div className="__section--left">Duration</div>
        <div className="__section--right border">
            {item.durationHours} Hours
            {item.durationMinutes} Minutes
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactjs JSX Syntax for IF else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089394/reactjs-jsx-syntax-for-if-else)

Comment: check the [**DOC for Conditional Rendering**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)

Comment: check this also: [Is it possible to use if…else… statement in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ternary expression
`condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse`

so it will be something like this

```
<div className="row">
  //if condition needs to go here
  { this.state.something === 'something' ?
  <div className="__section--left">Duration</div>
  <div className="__section--right border">
    {item.durationHours} Hours
    {item.durationMinutes} Minutes
  </div>
  : null }
</div>
```

In above code, if condition true you return some component and if false you return nothing.